# Strict Riesz's rearrangement inequality when function is not nonnegative

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

The strict Riesz rearrangement inequality  (Lieb- and Loss's book *Analysis*, Section 3, Theorem 3.9 ,page 93) says that if the functions $f,g,h,$ are all *nonnegative* and $g$ is *strictly* symmetric decreasing, then the Riesz rearrangement inequality holds and the "=" sign holds iff $f$ and $h$ are translation of $f^*, h^*$. Namely if $f,g,h,$ are all nonnegative, then
$$
\iint\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n} f(x) g(x-y) h(y) \, dx\,dy 
\le \iint\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n} f^*(x) g^*(x-y) h^*(y) \, dx\,dy \label{1}\tag{1}$$
and if $g$ is strictly symmetric decreasing, then there is an equality only if $f=T(f^*), h=T(h^*)$ for some translation $T$. I want to ask when remove the nonnegativity condition of $g$, in order to apply the result to functions such as $g(x)=-\ln(x)$, whether the "=" sign holds iff $f$ and $h$ are translation of $f^*, h^*$.  Because when $g(x)=-\ln x$, it is a strictly symmetric decreasing but not nonnegative: in this case, we know that (1) still holds. Does the equality in \eqref{1} holds only if $f$ and $h$ are a translation of $f^*, h^*$?